# Can you unlock secret stamps before beating the game?

Tags: storyteller

After getting every crown in Storyteller, I unlocked a list of achievements called the Secret Stamp Collection. If I met the requirements for one of these stamps before beating the game, could I unlock the stamp before knowing the requirements?

[image: Secret Stamp Collection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot unlock stamps before beating the game. I unintentionally met the conditions for a few stamps during my playthrough, (Second Chance, Excesses, Crown Secrets), but my stamp book had no stamps completed when I unlocked it.